# Let $A=\{0,5,\pi\}$. Find $\mathcal{P}(A)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{0,5,\pi\}$. Find $\mathcal{P}(A)$.

$A$ is a set of elements and $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is the set of sets? Am I understanding power sets correctly?

Does that make $\mathcal{P}(A)=(0,5,\pi)$?

Brackets { } indicate elements in a set and ( ) indicate sets? Is it that simple?

Comment: () aren't used when talking about sets (unless it happens to be a part of the notation of the element of the set).

Comment: Also, given a set $A$ of size $n$, $\mathcal{P}(A)$ will have size $2^n$, so your $\mathcal{P}(A)$ will have $2^3 = 8$ elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power-set $\mathcal P(A)$ is the *set of subsets* of $A$. So here we have
$$
\mathcal P(A)=\bigl\{\varnothing,\{0\},\{5\},\{\pi\},\{0,5\},\{0,\pi\},\{5,\pi\},\{0,5,\pi\}\bigr\}
$$